# 'dotnet build' command not finding NuGet packages (they exist)

Tags: c#, docker, jenkins, .net-core, nuget

I'm trying to build my .NET Core 2.1 application from the command-line on my Jenkins server.

It builds fine on my local machine (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise), and if I manually build it on the server Jenkins is running on (manually checkout Git repository and running `dotnet build`). It's only when I'm doing it through Jenkins in a Docker container that it fails.

The error:
`/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers, version 2.6.2 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/pr-builder/jobs/cgi-api/branches/PR-18/workspace/API/API.csproj]`

The package exists in `~/.nuget/packages/`.

I'm aware my Jenkinsfile is a bit weird at the moment, but that has to do with me trying to make this all work. It seems `dotnet restore` is working fine, but `dotnet build` is somehow not locating these files.

I've tried specifying the package directory (through the environment variable, with `dotnet restore --sources` and `dotnet build --sources`.

I attached pretty much anything I could think of at the moment, but if I forgot something please tell. I'm pretty lost at the moment.

My Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk'
        }
    }
    environment {
        HOME           = '.'
        NUGET_PACKAGES = './.nuget/packages/'
    }
    stages {
        stage('pre-build') {
            steps {
                // logging tooling versions
                sh 'dotnet --info'
                sh 'find ~/.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/ -type f'
                sh 'dotnet nuget locals all --list'
                sh 'dotnet restore'
                // sh 'dotnet clean'
            }
        }
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                // sh 'dotnet restore --force --no-cache'
                // sh 'ls ./packages/'
                // sh 'find ./packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/ -type f'
                sh 'dotnet build --no-restore'
            }
        }
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                sh 'no test project configured'
                // sh 'dotnet test'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.6.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet></CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Features>IOperation</Features>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Some build details:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
```

Inside docker container:

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.403
 Commit:    04e15494b6

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  9
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.9-arm
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.5
  Commit:  290303f510

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.403 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

---

```
$ find ./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/ -type f
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/analyzers/dotnet/vb/Microsoft.CodeQuality.VisualBasic.Analyzers.dll
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/analyzers/dotnet/vb/Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.dll
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.dll
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.CodeQuality.CSharp.Analyzers.dll
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/.signature.p7s
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/ThirdPartyNotices.rtf
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/build/Microsoft.CodeQuality.CSharp.Analyzers.props
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/build/Microsoft.CodeQuality.VisualBasic.Analyzers.props
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/build/Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.props
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/DesignRulesEnabled.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/DocumentationRulesDefault.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/PerformanceRulesDefault.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/UsageRulesDefault.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/ReliabilityRulesDefault.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/MaintainabilityRulesDefault.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/SecurityRulesDefault.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/PerformanceRulesEnabled.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/MaintainabilityRulesEnabled.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/UsageRulesEnabled.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/DocumentationRulesEnabled.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/ReliabilityRulesEnabled.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/AllRulesEnabled.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/NamingRulesEnabled.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/AllRulesDisabled.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/SecurityRulesEnabled.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/DesignRulesDefault.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/NamingRulesDefault.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/rulesets/AllRulesDefault.ruleset
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/microsoft.codequality.analyzers.2.6.2.nupkg.sha512
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/microsoft.codequality.analyzers.2.6.2.nupkg
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/microsoft.codequality.analyzers.nuspec
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/tools/uninstall.ps1
./.nuget/packages/microsoft.codequality.analyzers/2.6.2/tools/install.ps1
```

---

```
$ dotnet nuget locals all --list
info : http-cache: ./.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache
info : global-packages: ./.nuget/packages/
info : temp: /tmp/NuGetScratch
info : plugins-cache: ./.local/share/NuGet/plugins-cache
```

---

```
$ dotnet restore

  Restoring packages for /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/pr-builder/jobs/cgi-api/branches/PR-18/workspace/API/API.csproj...

  Restore completed in 13.5 sec for /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/pr-builder/jobs/cgi-api/branches/PR-18/workspace/API/API.csproj.
```

---

```
$ dotnet build --no-restore

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers, version 2.6.2 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/pr-builder/jobs/cgi-api/branches/PR-18/workspace/API/API.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers, version 2.6.2 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/pr-builder/jobs/cgi-api/branches/PR-18/workspace/API/API.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Comment: Try making a copy of the bin folder and then delete the bin folder.  It sounds like some of the files are not rebuilding properly when you move to the new PC.  Deleting the bin folder will force everything of rebuild.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this hasn't resolved my issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by specifying where `dotnet build` should look for the NuGet packages. It that within the image it doesn't look at the right location (although I'm not sure where it *is* looking either...)

I've specified the location with the `--packages` option. This option is listed in the `dotnet restore` documentation, but not in the `dotnet build` ones, even though it is available there as well (and you need it there, specifically).

You can specify it as follows:

```
dotnet restore --packages <path>
```

and

```
dotnet build --packages <path>
```

It works with the `--no-restore` option as well, if you need that.

---

My final Jenkinsfile looks as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk'
        }
    }
    environment {
        HOME = '.'
    }
    stages {
        stage('pre-build') {
            steps {
                // logging tooling versions
                sh 'dotnet --info'
                sh 'dotnet nuget locals all --list'
                sh 'dotnet clean'
            }
        }
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'dotnet build --packages ./.nuget/packages'
            }
        }
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo no test project configured'
                // sh 'dotnet test'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is I want touse custom package also? How Can I reference ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"It that within the image"* (seems incomprehensible)?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue solved by clearing global packages and cache with `dotnet nuget locals all --clear` as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting#other-potential-conditions).